# Oxidation of zinc in NaCl solution

Tags: electrochemistry

I'm working with a zinc sheet in water + Nacl solution, I have adjusted the pH to 10 to develop a ZnO layer and prevent all the faradaic reactions (passivation state). I've removed the oxygen with a pump (I've added nitrogen too). In this system, what are the reactions that could appear? How can I prevent them?